# Shallow Copy Constructor Problems in Static memory Allocation?

Tags: c++, oop, memory, memory-management

**Shallow Copy :**`When we initalize one object with another then the compiler copies state of one object to the other using copy constructor by assigning data member values of previous object to newly created object.`

**Problem in Shallow Copy**

- Dangling Pointer (Pointer pointing to incorrect memory location).
- Update data on that memory location.

In Copy constructor `two objects` points to the same `memory location` and then the above two problem can take place. I have studied that these two problem take place when `memory is allocated dynamically`. if not `dynamic memory` is involved then it works fine.

**Question:**
My question is if static memory is allocated to an object at compile time, and at run time on by performing some event i initialize another object from that object who have already assigned memory statically. Then also same problem will come or not? if not why and how? The memory location is same to which both objects are pointing. Then why `Dangling Pointer` problem will not come.

Comment: Can you demonstrate your question with sample code?

Comment: Now, please write 100 time "I shall **not** add C tag for C++ questions!"

Comment: An _object_ does not point anywhere, as it is not a pointer. However, you might have a _pointer_ or _reference_ to an object, or a pointer-member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if static memory is allocated to an object at compile time, and at run time on by performing some event i initialize another object from that object who have already assigned memory statically. Then also same problem will come or not? if not why and how?

you will have two objects with pointers pointing to the same instance, so both will modify the same object. The problem with dynamic memory allocation is that it must be at some point released, so if one object releases it then the second will release already freed memory - which is Undefined Behaviour. So with static object case, there is no problem with "dangling pointer", because you cannot release its memory (and should not try), so you will not have UB.

Comment: In Static object case, both are pointing to same instance, so if one modifies , the second will also get the modified values...? Am i right..? The memory location is same..??

Comment: then the `Dangling Pointer` problem will also take place in case of Static objects pointing to same instance...??

Comment: @ShahidIqbal no, your pointer will be always valid, pointer to static memory cannot be used by `delete`, so you pointer will always be valid. In dynamic memory case you free memory in destructor of one of your objects, but the other object has no idea about it and at some point also frees using the same pointer - which at this point is Dangling Pointer - it points to invalid memory.

Comment: Also: `static memory is allocated to an object at compile time` - is not quiet  right, it is not allocated, it is rather reserved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84594/discussion-between-shahid-iqbal-and-marcinj).

Answer (score 1):

> In Copy constructor two objects points to the same memory location and then the above two problem can take place. I have studied that these two problem take place when memory is allocated dynamically. if not dynamic memory is involved then it works fine.

This isn't strictly true (though it would be a rare problem):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Example
{
public:
    Example(int * const in) : p{in} {}

    int value() const { return *p; }
    int value(const int v) const { *p = v; return *p; }

private:
    int * p;
};

static int a = 5;
static Example first{&a};
// `first` now holds a pointer to `a`
static Example second = first;
// Now `first` and `second` hold pointers to the same static memory

int main()
{
    // Outputs `true`
    cout << boolalpha << (first.value() == second.value()) << endl;

    first.value(7);

    // Because they point to the same memory, this will output `true`
    cout << boolalpha << (first.value() == second.value()) << endl;
}
```

> My question is if static memory is allocated to an object at compile time, and at run time on by performing some event i initialize another object from that object who have already assigned memory statically. Then also same problem will come or not? if not why and how?

You'll still have the same problem of

> Update data on that memory location.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Example
{
public:
    Example(int * const in) : p{in} {}

    int value() const { return *p; }
    int value(const int v) const { *p = v; return *p; }

private:
    int * p;
};

static int a = 5;
static Example first{&a};
// `first` now holds a pointer to `a`

int main()
{
    Example * second = new Example(first); // implicit copy constructor
    // Now `first` and `second` hold pointers to the same static memory,
    // though `second` is allocated dynamically

    // Outputs `true`
    cout << boolalpha << (first.value() == second->value()) << endl;

    first.value(7);

    // Because they point to the same memory, this will still output `true`
    cout << boolalpha << (first.value() == second->value()) << endl;
}
```